# Is it possible to get Caller information inside Azure policy

Tags: azure-policy

Is it possible to get `caller` information from JSON Write request on resource when policy is evaluated? I'd like to put information about who commited Write statement on resource into tag and not sure if this information can be pulled from inside Azure policy.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to get caller information within a policy. Unfortunately policy is not "user-aware" so it is not possible to add a tag of user name. I know this is something that people have asked for and I recommend voicing your feature request in Microsoft's UserVoice for Azure Governance found [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915958-azure-governance)

-Kemley